# Linux Mint filesystem full despite home directory being virtually empty. SDA6 file/folder 98% full?

Tags: filesystems, linux-mint, storage

I have Mint installed on an 80GB partition. When I boot up, Mint tells me that "filesystem" is almost full. I typed "df -h" into the the terminal and this is the output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           737M  1.6M  735M   1% /run
/dev/sda6        59G   55G  1.2G  98% /
tmpfs           3.6G   30M  3.6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       511M   24K  511M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           737M   36K  737M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p1  1.9G   80M  1.8G   5% /media/user/Memory card
/dev/sda2       178G   66G  113G  37% /media/user/
```

It seems to show that /dev/sda6 is using 55GB of the 80GB partition and that it is 98% full, however I am unsure what sda6 even is. I cannot delete it and it doesn't seem to be a file or folder. What are these sda files, why do they take up so much space and how do I reduce the usage? I simply installed Mint on an 80GB partition and use the home directory to store small files like documents and C code.

EDIT: output of lsblk:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    50M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0   178G  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0   499M  0 part 
├─sda4        8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5        8:5    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda6        8:6    0  59.5G  0 part /run/timeshift/backup
mmcblk0     179:0    0   1.9G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   1.9G  0 part
```

Comment: Could you also post the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: @user1686 I have just added the output - I have no idea why there are 6 partitions. I have only 1 hard drive. I installed windows on this hard drive and then created a single 60GB (I thought I had done 80GB) partition which I installed Mint on, though I never use Windows anymore, I do have files and programs installed on Windows.

Comment: Are you using Btrfs? What does `lsblk -f` show about the contents? I guess you ended up with 2 or 3 "EFI system partitions", or maybe there's a Windows Recovery partition somewhere in there... I don't see a Windows C: partition though.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what it shows. `df` doesn't look for large files or anything like that; it only shows global filesystem statistics, and the first column in df's output shows you the device that each filesystem is *stored on.*

So `/dev/sda6` isn't occupying any space on the partition; rather, it *literally is* the partition itself. (If you tried to "reduce its size" the partition would become smaller, and you wouldn't gain space, you would actually lose space.)

(Most paths under /dev, such as /dev/sda, represent devices in one way or another. They don't occupy any space themselves; in fact they're not even *on* your disk – they're all kept in memory; notice that 'df' shows a whole another filesystem mounted on `/dev`.)

So the important part of `df` output is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
.........        59G   55G  1.2G  98% /
```

which means that your `/` filesystem is 60 GB in size (not 80 GB!), and various files are occupying 55 GB in total. You could use tools like `sudo ncdu -x /` to find the actual large files.

(Additionally, 5% of the filesystem's total space, i.e. 3.0 GB out of the total 60 GB, is *reserved* for use by system services in case the filesystem fills up, so it is subtracted from 'Avail'. This percentage can be changed through `tune2fs -m`.)

Comment: Okay thanks, that's cleared a lot of confusion! This is probably a whole other question in itself, but any suggestions on what commonly causes the filesystem to full up despite actually having a very small number of files?

Comment: It could have a very small number of *very large* files. Keep in mind that `/` isn't just your own files but also the entirely of Mint OS; it's like the C: disk that also stores C:\Windows. So if e.g. you install a huge app or something, it necessarily consumes space on `/`.

Comment: If it's a Btrfs filesystem with a large amount of snapshots (such as if you're using timeshift), then space will be occupied not only by current files but also by historical snapshots.